# Building height adjustable desk

Tags: pcb, dc-motor, h-bridge

I'm building a memory preset control panel for my adjustable height desk.

I have an electric desk running with a 3A/24V motor with an up/down switch and SMPS.

To add the memory functionality, I am planning to buy a Pi Pico module and a 3A motor driver circuit.

1. Will this setup work? Are there any redundancies in my setup?
2. I'm planning to program the Pi Pico to move motor at determined inches per second with a determined volt and current. Will this work? (What will happen if the load/weight on the table increases? Will this logic still work?)

Comment: 1. what setup? ... 2. unknown, see 1.

Comment: Redundancies I did not note any but a lot of information is missing. For example how do you know where the desk is. What happens during power failure. Since you are using a predetermined velocity what if it changes or gets stuck, these are just a few items I see missing.

Comment: Setup -> Pi Pico - Motor Driver - Motor

Comment: How do I know where the desk is  - Store an initial position  - X cm. If the Motor can move Y cm per second, current position= X+Y.

Comment: What happens during a power failure - Current position will be stored in Pi Pico and it will be taken as previous position when next power ON

Answer (score 0):

While voltage to the motor will be constant, if you want to maintain a specific speed, the current delivered to the motor will vary based on the weight of the desk.

How will you be ensuring the motor's speed? You will likely want an encoder in a feedback loop with some sort of PID control. This may be overengineering, but would ensure a constant motor speed regardless of external variables.

Comment: Ok got it ! Is there anyway we can handle without Encoder? Is  the encoder needed only because the weight can vary which varies the current?

Comment: An encoder will be provide you information that you can use to infer the speed the desk is moving. From there you can say if it needs to move faster or slower to maintain your desired speed